# How to use SQL procedure to add new attribute and update the value at the same time?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, procedure

I'm trying to create a procedure which (1)adds new attribute called 'Hours' to table called 'Project' (if it does not have the 'Hour' attribute) and (2)initialize the value of 'Hour' to 0.0. Below is the code I tried (using myPhpAdmin) but it gives me SQL syntax error. What did I do wrong?

The error message says "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near `'UPDATE Project SET Hours = 0.0 where Project.Pnumber = p end if; end'` "

```
delimiter &
create procedure init(in p int(11))
begin
    declare attNum int;
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO attNum FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
        WHERE table_schema = 'MyDB'
        AND table_name = 'Project';
    if attNum < 5 then ALTER TABLE Project ADD Hours float; 
    end if;

     SELECT * FROM Project 
     where Project.Pnumber = p 
     UPDATE Project SET Hours = 0.0
     where Project.Pnumber = p
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Semicolon is missing in the end of Select and Update query in Stored procedure creation query.

Corrected Query:

```
delimiter &
create procedure init(in p int(11))
begin
    declare attNum int;
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO attNum FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
        WHERE table_schema = 'MyDB'
        AND table_name = 'Project';
    if attNum < 5 then ALTER TABLE Project ADD Hours float; 
    end if;

     SELECT * FROM Project 
     where Project.Pnumber = p;
     UPDATE Project SET Hours = 0.0
     where Project.Pnumber = p;
end
```

Comment: Thanks so much Nishant! I spent last 1 hour struggling because of missing a colon!

Answer (score 1):

> (1)adds new attribute called 'Hours' to table called 'Project' (if it does not have the 'Hour' attribute) and (2)initialize the value of 'Hour' to 0.0.

Why would you use a stored procedure for this?  In any case, you can do this with `alter table` and a `default` value:

```
alter table project add hours float default 0.0
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4ce86eccc97fbf9396e26cdd3c9ec415) is a db<>fiddle.

I do not recommend wrapping such logic in a stored procedure.  Presumably, it is only being done once.  If you do need to do this in a stored procedure, just run the above command.  If the column already exists, MySQL returns an error -- and you can handle the error in the stored procedure.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer Gordon! I know that what I'm trying to do is very weird. But I really want to use procedure to Initialize the 'Hour' attribute as 0.0 only for a specific tuple I choose. For example, if I call "call init(5)", I only want to initialize the tuple with p = 5. Is there any other way to achieve this??

Comment: @jasone . . . That is not the question that you asked here.